# Adding Data-Attribute value to XML field does not work

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript, jquery

I have a form with dynamic fields. some items contain this input fields, some don't.

Here is my code for the XML :

```
$field = '<field name="id_'.$filter_record['id'].'_from" type="text"
                        label="From" description="'.$filter_record['name'].'"
                         size="'.$filter_record['holdout'].'" format="%Y-%m-%d"
                        maxlength="20"  
                        required="true"                                             
                        class = "datefrom"      
                        data-holdout="7"                        
                        filter="user_utc" />
```

as you can see, I have a size attribute there which contains a dynamic value. Now when I want to use the data-holdout in the front-end,

using this code:

```
var x = jQuery(".datefrom").data("holdout");
```

when I alert the value of x it says undefined.

How should I add the custom attribute for it to be seen in the front page?

Comment: `datafrom` is probably incorrect. Inspect the element in your browser to get  the ID from it, then use that in your jQuery

Comment: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/16141

Answer (score 2):

The JFormField of Type Text does not support the data-* attribute, so your line

```
data-holdout="7"
```

in your XML file won't have any effect on your input text HTML element, ie your input element won't have a data-holdout="7" attribute and `.data("holdout");` will return undefined on that element.

With a custom JFormField you can support all attributes that you need. Here is a tutorial how to build a custom JFormField: https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type

By the way: JFormFieldText (which you are using through 'type="text"' in your XML) does not support the `format` attribute either. You should probably have a look at the [calendar form field type](https://docs.joomla.org/Calendar_form_field_type).

Comment: Msg by Dean "@fruppel that's pretty standard behavior with most frameworks to assign custom attributes on form elements. It's pretty heavy for very mundane task like this to create a custom JFORM element for something simple. "